# how to set working range for orbit controls in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create an orientation cube in threeJS and I have created 2 scenes with two viewports and cameras and their own controls.

fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/simar_aneja/kwef9vgs/11/)

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( view.camera, container.domElement );
```

as you can run in the fiddle and see that orbit controls for the main scene are working very smoothly and the range is more based on the size of the domElement.

the same thing is not happening in the smaller scene because I am having single renderer and don't have resized domElement to attach for smaller window scene.
as its controls are attached with main DOM, that is why it is not rotating freely.

How can I solve this problem so that cube in the small scene should have more range to rotate inside.

see this [link](https://lucascassiano.github.io/react-cubeview/?selectedKind=react-cubeview&selectedStory=simple&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=kadirahq%2Fstorybook-addon-actions%2Factions-panel), but this renderer is set to smaller.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this problem so that cube in the small scene should have more range to rotate inside.

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to achieve this by setting `OrbitControls.rotateSpeed` to a higher value like in the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2asqm9zn/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I solved it by creating a new DIV around that cube scene and now working on making it synchronize.
But thanks for this information. It is really helpful for further cases.